# How can i register EID-frame beacon with beacon tools app? or something else?

Tags: eddystone, google-beacon-platform

I have two beacons which support **eddystone**. One of them broadcasts only **EID-frame**, and another beacon broadcasts only **UID-frame**.

I see only UID-frame beacon on beacon tools app and i can register uid-frame to google proximity api via **beacon tools app**.

But i can't register eid-frame beacon.

Because Even if i see the eid-frame beacon by other apps or altbeacon library, beacon tools app doesn't show eid-frame beacon.

I want to register eid-frame beacon to **google proximity api**.

**How can i register EID-frame beacon with beacon tools app? or something else?**

Answer (score 1):

To be able to see and register your Eddystone EID beacon in Beacon Tools app, you need to have the same service ECDH key (you can find more details [here](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/80752/error-registering-eid-eddystone-beacon/)).
But if you want just scan for the nearby Eddystone EID beacons, you can use some SDKs that has EID support, like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp).

Hope, it helps. Please let me know if you have any further questions!

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want to scan for nearby Eddystone EID beacons, you can also use a 3-rd party app like [this one](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp).